# Create arrays based on user input

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code takes the values from 3 input boxes, processes them into a string and stores it in an array. Each time the user presses the add button a new string is added to the array.

If the array does not exist it is created automatically at the beginning of my code.

However, I'd like to create a new array each time the user enters a "new" value in the "prefix" input box.

Can this be done?

```
function test(){
if(typeof uld === "undefined"){ 
    window.uld = [];
}

pre = document.getElementById("prefix").value.toUpperCase();
ser = document.getElementById("serial").value;
suf = document.getElementById("suffix").value.toUpperCase();

nbrUld = uld.length + 1

if (nbrUld == 1 || nbrUld % 5 == 1){ 
    uld.push(pre + "." + ser + suf); 
    uld2 = uld.join(''); 
} else if (nbrUld % 5 === 0){ 
    uld.push("/" + ser + suf + ".T" + "5\n");
    uld2 = uld.join(''); 
} else {
    uld.push("/" + ser + suf); 
    uld2 = uld.join(''); 
}
ttl = ".T" + nbrUld % 5;
if (nbrUld % 5 === 0){
    document.getElementById("scm").value = uld2;
} else {
    document.getElementById("scm").value = uld2+ttl
}
}
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but why are you using abbreviations for variable names? It makes your code quite hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert uld to an object to act as a hash. If the same prefix is used, the array will be replaced. just use push if this is not what the application needs.

```
function test(){
  if(typeof uld === "undefined"){
      window.uld = {};
  }

  pre = document.getElementById("prefix").value.toUpperCase();
  ser = document.getElementById("serial").value;
  suf = document.getElementById("suffix").value.toUpperCase();

  var newArr = [];
  uld[pre] = newArr;

  nbrUld = newArr.length + 1

  if (nbrUld == 1 || nbrUld % 5 == 1){
      newArr.push(pre + "." + ser + suf);
      uld2 = newArr.join('');
  } else if (nbrUld % 5 === 0){
      newArr.push("/" + ser + suf + ".T" + "5\n");
      uld2 = uld.join('');
  } else {
      newArr.push("/" + ser + suf);
      uld2 = newArr.join('');
  }
  ttl = ".T" + nbrUld % 5;
  if (nbrUld % 5 === 0){
      document.getElementById("scm").value = uld2;
  } else {
      document.getElementById("scm").value = uld2+ttl
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Radio. Your solution gives an error on line 14 "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: The error is gone but now the code doesn't work properly anymore. I'll have to take an look into it. Thanks for trying!

Comment: my guess would be whatever code was using uld as an array needs to be updated to use it as an object map of one to many arrays.

Comment: I'm quite new to JS. How do I do that?

Comment: There's not enough information to answer that. I would start a new question and see these guidelines to understand why you're getting down-voted:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask